# angularjs ng-repeat not update

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I used the ng-repeat in the ion-slide and operated the array myTags in the controller，ion-slide-tab-label was custom directive.When I changed the array，ng-repeat view has not changed.If I use the method remove() and then add() the same tag,it would be error：duplicate. Here's the code.

slidingTabsDirective.js

```
var slidingTabsDirective = angular.module("ionic").directive('ionSlideTabs', ['$timeout', '$compile', '$interval', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate', '$ionicGesture', function($timeout, $compile, $interval, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicGesture) {
return {
require: "^ionSlideBox",
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, parent) {

  var ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
  var ionicScrollDelegate;
  var ionicScrollDelegateID;

  var slideTabs;
  var indicator;

  var slider;
  var tabsBar;

  var options = {
    "slideTabsScrollable": true
  };


  var init = function() {

    if (angular.isDefined(attrs.slideTabsScrollable) && attrs.slideTabsScrollable == false) {
      options.slideTabsScrollable = false;
    }

    var tabItems = '<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in tabs" ng-click="onTabTabbed($event, {{key}})" class="slider-slide-tab" ng-bind-html="value"></li>';

    if (options.slideTabsScrollable) {
      //alert(options.slideTabsScrollable)

      ionicScrollDelegateID = "ion-slide-tabs-handle-" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
      tabsBar = angular.element('<ion-scroll delegate-handle="' + ionicScrollDelegateID + '" class="slidingTabs" direction="x" scrollbar-x="false"><ul>' + tabItems + '</ul> <div class="tab-indicator-wrapper"><div class="tab-indicator"></div></div> </ion-scroll>');

    } else {

      tabsBar = angular.element('<div class="slidingTabs"><ul>' + tabItems + '</ul> <div class="tab-indicator-wrapper"><div class="tab-indicator"></div></div> </div>');

    }


    slider = angular.element(element);

    var compiled = $compile(tabsBar);
    slider.parent().prepend(tabsBar);
    compiled(scope);

    //get Tabs DOM Elements
    indicator = angular.element(tabsBar[0].querySelector(".tab-indicator"));

    //get the slideBoxHandle
    var slideHandle = slider.attr('delegate-handle');
    var scrollHandle = tabsBar.attr('delegate-handle');

    ionicSlideBoxDelegate = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
    if (slideHandle) {
      ionicSlideBoxDelegate = ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle(slideHandle);
    }


    if (options.slideTabsScrollable) {

      ionicScrollDelegate = $ionicScrollDelegate;
      if (scrollHandle) {
        ionicScrollDelegate = ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(scrollHandle);
      }

    }


    addEvents();
    setTabBarWidth();
    slideToCurrentPosition();
  };

  var addEvents = function() {

    ionic.onGesture("dragleft", scope.onSlideMove, slider[0]);
    ionic.onGesture("dragright", scope.onSlideMove, slider[0]);
    ionic.onGesture("release", scope.onSlideChange, slider[0]);

  };

  var setTabBarWidth = function() {

    if (!angular.isDefined(slideTabs) || slideTabs.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }

    tabsList = tabsBar.find("ul");
    var tabsWidth = 0;

    angular.forEach(slideTabs, function(currentElement, index) {

      var currentLi = angular.element(currentElement);
      tabsWidth += currentLi[0].offsetWidth;
    });

    if (options.slideTabsScrollable) {

      angular.element(tabsBar[0].querySelector(".scroll")).css("width", tabsWidth + 1 + "px");

    } else {

      slideTabs.css("width", tabsList[0].offsetWidth / slideTabs.length + "px");
    }

    slideToCurrentPosition();
  };

  var slideToCurrentPosition = function() {

    if (!angular.isDefined(slideTabs) || slideTabs.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }

    var targetSlideIndex = ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();

    var targetTab = angular.element(slideTabs[targetSlideIndex]);
    var targetLeftOffset = targetTab.prop("offsetLeft");
    var targetWidth = targetTab[0].offsetWidth;



    indicator.css({
      "-webkit-transition-duration": "300ms",
      "-webkit-transform": "translate(" + targetLeftOffset + "px,0px)",
      "width": targetWidth + "px"
    });

    if (options.slideTabsScrollable && ionicScrollDelegate) {
      var scrollOffset = 40;
      ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(targetLeftOffset - scrollOffset, 0, true);
    }

    slideTabs.removeClass("tab-active");
    targetTab.addClass("tab-active");

  };


  var setIndicatorPosition = function(currentSlideIndex, targetSlideIndex, position, slideDirection) {

    var targetTab = angular.element(slideTabs[targetSlideIndex]);

    var currentTab = angular.element(slideTabs[currentSlideIndex]);
    var targetLeftOffset = targetTab.prop("offsetLeft");

    var currentLeftOffset = currentTab.prop("offsetLeft");
    var offsetLeftDiff = Math.abs(targetLeftOffset - currentLeftOffset);


    if (currentSlideIndex == 0 && targetSlideIndex == ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount() - 1 && slideDirection == "right" ||
      targetSlideIndex == 0 && currentSlideIndex == ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount() - 1 && slideDirection == "left") {
      return;
    }

    var targetWidth = targetTab[0].offsetWidth;
    var currentWidth = currentTab[0].offsetWidth;
    var widthDiff = targetWidth - currentWidth;

    var indicatorPos = 0;
    var indicatorWidth = 0;

    if (currentSlideIndex > targetSlideIndex) {

      indicatorPos = targetLeftOffset - (offsetLeftDiff * (position - 1));
      indicatorWidth = targetWidth - ((widthDiff * (1 - position)));

    } else if (targetSlideIndex > currentSlideIndex) {

      indicatorPos = targetLeftOffset + (offsetLeftDiff * (position - 1));
      indicatorWidth = targetWidth + ((widthDiff * (position - 1)));

    }


    indicator.css({
      "-webkit-transition-duration": "0ms",
      "-webkit-transform": "translate(" + indicatorPos + "px,0px)",
      "width": indicatorWidth + "px"
    });


    if (options.slideTabsScrollable && ionicScrollDelegate) {
      var scrollOffset = 40;
      ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(indicatorPos - scrollOffset, 0, false);
    }

  };

  scope.onTabTabbed = function(event, index) {
    ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
    slideToCurrentPosition();
  };

  scope.tabs = [];

  scope.addTabContent = function($content) {

    $content = $content.replace(/\“/g, '').replace(/\”/g, '');
    scope.tabs.push($content);
    scope.$apply();


    $timeout(function() {
      slideTabs = angular.element(tabsBar[0].querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll(".slider-slide-tab"));
      slideToCurrentPosition();
      setTabBarWidth();
    });

  };

  scope.onSlideChange = function(slideIndex) {
    slideToCurrentPosition();
  };

  scope.onSlideMove = function() {
    var scrollDiv = slider[0].getElementsByClassName("slider-slide");

    var currentSlideIndex = ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();
    var currentSlide = angular.element(scrollDiv[currentSlideIndex]);
    var currentSlideLeftOffset = currentSlide.css('-webkit-transform').replace(/[^0-9\-.,]/g, '').split(',')[0];

    var targetSlideIndex = (currentSlideIndex + 1) % scrollDiv.length;
    if (currentSlideLeftOffset > slider.prop("offsetLeft")) {
      targetSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;
      if (targetSlideIndex < 0) {
        targetSlideIndex = scrollDiv.length - 1;
      }
    }
    var targetSlide = angular.element(scrollDiv[targetSlideIndex]);

    var position = currentSlideLeftOffset / slider[0].offsetWidth;
    var slideDirection = position > 0 ? "right" : "left";
    position = Math.abs(position);

    setIndicatorPosition(currentSlideIndex, targetSlideIndex, position, slideDirection);
  };

  init();
},
controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.addTab = function($content) {
    $timeout(function() {
      if ($scope.addTabContent) {
        $scope.addTabContent($content);
      }
    });
  };
}]
};
}]);

slidingTabsDirective.directive('ionSlideTabLabel', [function() {
    return {
        require: "^ionSlideTabs",
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $parent) {
            $parent.addTab($attrs.ionSlideTabLabel);
        }
    };
}]);
```

index.html

```
<ion-slide-box id="slide_box" show-pager="false" ion-slide-tabs>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="tag in myTags track by $index" ion-slide-tab-label=“{{tag.tagname}}”>
    .........
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

service.js

```
function getTags() {
  var url = xxxxxxx;

  return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url
    })
    .success(function(res) {
      //console.log('is collect success');
    })
    .error(function(msg, code) {
      console.log('tag error.....', code);
    });
}
```

indexCtrl.js

```
$scope.tags = [];
$scope.myTags = [];
$scope.moreTags = [];

function getTags() {
    ds.getTags()
        .then(function(res) {
        var traTags = [];
        var l = res.data.length;
        $scope.tags = res.data;
        traTags = angular.copy($scope.tags);
        $scope.myTags = traTags.splice(0, l / 2);
        $scope.moreTags = traTags;
    });
}


function remove(index) {
    if (!$scope.lock) {
        $scope.moreTags.unshift($scope.myTags[index]);
        $scope.myTags.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function add(index) {
    $scope.myTags.push($scope.moreTags[index]);
    $scope.moreTags.splice(index, 1);
}
```

what should I do? please help me! Thank you!

Comment: try pass parameter in you services.js

Answer (score 0):

function:

```
function addlist(obj, item, addtype) {
      var isdata = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          if (obj[i] == item) {
              isdata = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      if (!isdata) {
          if (addtype) {
              obj.push(item);
          } else {
              obj.unshift(item);
          }
      }
  }
```

code:

```
        function remove(index) {
        if (!$scope.lock) {
            addlist($scope.moreTags,$scope.myTags[index],false);
            $scope.myTags.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    function add(index) {
        addlist($scope.myTags,$scope.moreTags[index],true);
        $scope.moreTags.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Comment: 谢谢。但这个方法不起作用，ng-repeat还是没有更新。